# Can you patch your lawn using not the entire roll but pieces of it?

Tags: lawn

I have small holes or gaps in my lawn because of squirrel work or because lawn died. Can I cut pieces from a roll and patch as needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, MiniMe!  Why do you have extra pieces of sod lying around?  Have you just recently installed sod?  No matter, I would throw the big piece over what you want to fix and first cut the edge if it is on the edge and then cut a chunk of the sod to easily cover the damaged parts... the size of whatever would take the place of a number of little holes all together. Don't worry about the exact damage make the damaged parts fit the sod you cut. Cut deeply enough to show through to the existing sod.  Cut the existing sod out using those cuts as guidelines, then pull it out and replace.  Larger pieces do better than teeny tiny pieces.

I've never seen lawn damaged by squirrels.  They are very careful about making their digging obvious to protect their stash.  I have seen peanut plants growing up in the lawn but that is no big deal.  What do you think caused death of lawn in spots?  Is this since the snow melted if you know what I am getting at?

Having chunks of sod around is so smart!  They last for months laid out on gravel and watered.  Send a picture of what you are doing.  Do you have a true sod knife?  Sure makes a difference.

Comment: Small holes in the ground like they are digging for something they berried there previously. It may be from raccoons also. Maybe I will take a picture tomorrow for the dead patches (practically gaps)

Comment: Raccoons, love those little poops.  Let's talk about a brilliant animal. When they kill a chicken, they surgically remove organs and other parts to organize them on the lawn or wherever.  In straight lines or grouped perfectly.  Certainly they are able to smell for squirrel stash. Just throw a scoop of soil in the holes to level the hole to the main surface and then fill  with a chunk of sod.  Seeding is really a silly exercise.  Hydroseeding makes sense.  Sod is the only way to go.